# How store class objects in vector<vector<class *>> and access and pass them to function either by reference or value

Tags: c++, object, pointers, vector

```
#ifndef BINARY_TREE_H
#define BINARY_TREE_H

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Binary_Tree;

static int levelCount=0;

extern vector<vector<Binary_Tree*>> vec;
extern vector<Binary_Tree*> tempVec;

class Binary_Tree
{
  public:
     Binary_Tree()
     {
        childNum=0;
        data=0;
        level=0;
        prev=NULL;
        next[0]=NULL;
        next[1]=NULL;
    };

    Binary_Tree(int d)
    {
         childNum=0;
         data=d;
         level=0;
         prev=NULL;
         next[0]=NULL;
         next[1]=NULL;
         levelCount++;
     }


    void insert_node(int,int,int);

    int get_level();

    int get_childCount();

    friend int set_childNum(Binary_Tree*);

private:
    int childNum;
    int data;
    int level;
    Binary_Tree *prev;
    Binary_Tree *next[2];
};

#endif // BINARY_TREE_H
```

Here is the implementation file

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include "Binary_Tree.h"

using namespace std;



void Binary_Tree::insert_node(int lev, int d, int sib)
{
if(vec.empty())
{
    cout<<"You Have to create Root first";
}

else
{
    if(set_childNum(vec[lev][sib-1])==0)
    {
        cout<<"Child cant be created parent Node already has two childs.";
    }

    else
    {
        childNum=set_childNum(vec[lev][sib-1]);
        data=d;
        level=lev+1;
        prev=vec[lev][sib];
        next[0]=NULL;
        next[1]=NULL;
        tempVec.clear();
        for(int i=0; i<pow(2,(lev+1)); i++)
        {
            if(i==childNum-1)
            {
                tempVec.push_back(this);
            }
            else
            tempVec.push_back(vec[lev][i]);
        }
        vector<vector<Binary_Tree*>>::iterator itr=vec.begin()+(lev+1);
        vec.erase(itr);
        vec.insert(itr,tempVec);
       }
   }
}

int set_childNum(Binary_Tree *lstNdAdr)
{
    if(lstNdAdr->get_childCount()==0)
        return 1;

    else if(lstNdAdr->get_childCount()==1)
        return 2;

    else
      return 0;
}

int Binary_Tree::get_level()
{
    return level;
}

int Binary_Tree::get_childCount()
{
  if(next[0]==NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  else if(next[0]!=NULL && next[1]==NULL)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  else
  {
    return 2;
  }


}
```

MAIN.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include"Binary_Tree.h"

using namespace std;

vector<vector<Binary_Tree*>> vec;
vector<Binary_Tree*> tempVec;


int main()
{
  Binary_Tree tree;
  here:
  cout<<"Enter your Choice:1.Create Root Of Tree\n"
      <<"2.Insert node\n"<<endl;

  int choice;
  cin>>choice;

  switch(choice)
  {
    case 1:
      {
        int d;
        cout<<"Enter Data to insert: ";
        cin>>d;

         Binary_Tree treeDummy(d);

         tree=treeDummy;

         tempVec.push_back(&tree);

         vec.push_back(tempVec);
       }

     break;

    case 2:
    {
        int lev;
        int sibbling;
        int d;
        cout<<"Enter at which level and data and parent's sibling-no.: ";
        cin>>lev;
        cin>>d;
        cin>>sibbling;

        if(sibbling>pow(2,lev))
            cout<<"Illegal Sibbling Number."<<endl;
        else
            tree.insert_node(lev,d,sibbling);

    }
    break;
}
int x;
cin>>x;
if(x==5)
{
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    goto here;

}

  return 0;
}
```

in above code i am trying to create a binary tree type structure which can be manipulated  and traversed dynamically that is any node can be inserted and can be removed at run time (although its incomplete because i am stuck at a problem). While pushing back the `tempVec` vector the code produces a segmentation fault and i am also doubtful in passing the object stored in vetcor> vec to the functions in the implementation (I am new to Stl and first time dealing with vector of vectors containing pointer to the class types)

Comment: if `i!=1`, `foo(vec[0][0])` invokes UB

Comment: @UDB how do you know `tempVec.push_back(&obj1);` is the line that's actually segfaulting and not somewhere else?

Comment: @billzi have said it already that it is not the actual code i am working on

Comment: It does not look like your simplified example is representative of the real problem you're having in your actual program.

Comment: @greatwolf by trying to watch and debugging

Comment: @UDB no segfault happens [here](http://ideone.com/kxOIP9) when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

The nested vector's entries are only filled  if `i` is set to `1`. But you attempt to access its element `[0][0]` regardless. You have out of bounds access when `i` is not `1`.

Comment: that is not true. it lives in whole main()

Comment: @BЈовић I couldn't delete, so I changed the answer to mention one obvious error.

Comment: @juanchopanza i think every one is misunderstanding the scenario, just have a look i am adding actual code

Comment: @UDB then you should post some code that reproduces the problem, instead of posting something with gratuitous errors.

Comment: @juanchopanza now have a look

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems present in your code, that and combined with the poor style and formatting makes it not so fun to debug.

```
   Binary_Tree treeDummy(d);
   tree = treeDummy;

   tempVec.push_back(&tree);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but the above looks wrong. You are shallow copying treeDummy's data over to tree. You'll lose the link to whatever child node tree points to. Afterwards you're pushing that same tree instance into your temporary vector. That means all the elements in your vector ends up pointing to the local variable `tree` in `main`. So even if no segfault occurred you would run into aliasing problems since they all refer to the same `tree` object and not a separate unique `BinaryTree` instance.

```
  vector< vector<Binary_Tree*> >::iterator itr=vec.begin()+(lev+1);
  vec.erase(itr);
  vec.insert(itr,tempVec);
```

Your `BinaryTree::insert_node` is using an invalidated iterator after performing `erase` which is undefined behavior.

```
  childNum = set_childNum(vec[lev][sib-1]);
  // ...
  prev = vec[lev][sib];
```

The above can access an out-of-bound index in your vector. eg. You push_back a `tempVec` with only 1 element in it and then call `insert_node` with `sib` = 1.

```
 // ...
 if(x == 5)
 {
   cout<<endl<<endl;
   goto here;
 }
```

The use of `goto` is also completely unnecessary here and should be replaced with a traditional while loop that checks for `condition != 5`.

The higher level problem in your program, however, is that there's no clear constraints and invariants in its design. What assumptions and preconditions do each of those functions need to work? Why use vectors to hold `BinaryTree` nodes when the class itself should be dealing with that. You should get the overall design sorted out first, otherwise you'll just play whack-a-mole as other bugs crop up.

Comment: thanks for the response and advice on poor design issues. I am going to start it from scratch with new design.

Comment: @UDB Check out and readup on Test Driven Development before you do so.